# JAXB javaType override, but XmlJavaTypeAdapter Adapter1 cannot be resolved

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I use an XML schema to generate `JAXB` classes. Part of my schema uses an inline `javaType` to reassign the `dateTime` type to `java.util.Calendar`, as shown below:

```
<element name="lastChangedDate" type="dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" id="lastChangedDate">
    <annotation>
        <appinfo>
            <jxb:javaType
                name="java.util.Calendar"
                parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate"
                printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDate" />
        </appinfo>
    </annotation>
 </element>
```

The generated class consequently includes the following generated class member declaration:

```
@XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected Calendar lastChangedDate;
```

As you can see, the `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation value of `Adapter1` is garbage, I don't know what an `Adapter1` is, and neither does my compiler.

What can I do to my schema to generate working output here?

(BTW, I'm a JAXB noob, trying to make sense of stuff other people have done, sorry if the answer is obvious).

Comment: If anyone is looking for how to create this type of adapter for dateTime, please also consider using DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime and printDateTime instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found it. The class Adapter1.java is generated in the xjc output package. When I refresh my IDE the new file appears, gets compiled, and works.

Hopefully this helps someone else.